# mysql—wired problems after sql import on remote host

Tags: mysql

I would like to import a local *.sql dump at a remote host. Therefore I am running this command:

```
mysql -u<user> -p<pass> -h<remote.host> <db> < /path/to/dump.sql
```

The command runs successfully and the data is imported as expected, or at least it looks like on the first glance. Since it is a dump of a joomla installation I cannot login a the remote website anymore. After a password reset in the database it works again.

Might I run into encoding problems?

Comment: may you can test the raw tables from mysql or Workbench?

Comment: not sure what you mean with this, but i can login to the remote host from my local machine using mysql and running sql-statements. When I check the user table, the data is present.

Comment: try to compare data with WinMerge or similar.

Comment: I compared the password, nevertheless that it is encryted, it is imported exactly as it was exported. I somehow think that it is a Joomla Problem, but I have no clue where it comes from.