# Joomla—wired: login does not work after page move

Tags: joomla, build-automation, mysql

I am a local Joomla installation and a buildr script which exports this page to a remote host. The whole page is zipped, uploaded and unzippped on the remote host, via scp and ssh. The database is exported directly using:

```
mysql -u<user> -p<pass> -h<remote.host> <db> < dump.sql
```

If I look on the page after the export, on the remote host everything shows up as it should, but I cannot login to the backend any more. If I import the page (running the whole process in opposite direction) I can still login.

I emptied the browser cache and tried to reset the password in the database, but it just refuses to work remotely. I have moved Joomla websites a thousand times, even in automated fashion, but i never ran in that problem before. What could cause that, can encoding issues by responsible for that?

Comment: Try to restore password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql—wired problems after sql import on remote host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956376/mysqlwired-problems-after-sql-import-on-remote-host)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. You can always **edit** your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The `<prefix_>session` table has to be empty. After excluding this table from the dump and drop/create it everything worked fine.

I thinks this is new to Joomla! 3.2 because it never happened to me before.